# Moving xml nodes to other nodes if some of their node values are equal(using XSLT)

Tags: xslt

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <cases>
      <case>
         <key>123</key>
      </case>
      <case>
         <key>456</key>
      </case>
   </cases>
   <issues>
      <issue>
         <issueid>issue1</issueid>
         <casekey>123</casekey>
      </issue>
      <issue>
         <issueid>issue2</issueid>
         <casekey>123</casekey>
      </issue>
      <issue>
         <issueid>issue3</issueid>
         <casekey>456</casekey>
      </issue>
   </issues>
</root>
```

I want to move all the `<issue>` nodes to the `<case>` whose `<casekey>` value equal to the `<key>` value of `<case>`.

In other words, if the `<casekey>` value of an `<issue>` is equal to to the `<key>` value of `<case>`, then move that `issue` under the `case`.

My final xml should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <cases>
      <case>
         <key>123</key>
         <issue>
            <issueid>issue1</issueid>
            <casekey>123</casekey>
         </issue>
         <issue>
            <issueid>issue2</issueid>
            <casekey>123</casekey>
         </issue>
      </case>
      <case>
         <key>456</key>
         <issue>
            <issueid>issue3</issueid>
            <casekey>456</casekey>
         </issue>
      </case>
   </cases>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key)** mechanism for resolving cross-references - it's best to use it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="issues" match="issue" use="casekey" />

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
        <cases>
            <xsl:for-each select="cases/case">
                <case>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="key('issues', key)"/>
                </case>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </cases>
        </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

P.S. Do not confuse a reference to the `key` element in your XML with the `xsl:key` instruction and the `key()` function.

Comment: Super!! Interesting solution...!! +1 for fine solution

Answer (score 1):

The main point is a template matching *case*, including:

- Something similar to the *identity template*.
- But before closing *xsl:copy* there is another *xsl:apply-templates*,
  to process respective issues.

The final thing to add is to block "normal" processing of *issues* tag.

Below you have a working solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="case">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:variable name="kk" select="key"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../issues/issue[casekey=$kk]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="issues"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Nice explanation. But solution provided by michael.hor257k appears to be simpler. +1 for quick response. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="cases"/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="case">
    <xsl:variable name="keyvalue" select="normalize-space(key/text())"/>

    <case>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key"/>
        <xsl:if test="ancestor::cases/following-sibling::issues/descendant::casekey = $keyvalue">
            <xsl:copy-of
                select="ancestor::cases/following-sibling::issues/issue[casekey = $keyvalue]"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </case>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="issue[child::casekey = preceding::key]"/>


<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```